# Ordeby(), Where(), etc. used in a function with generic types

Tags: c#, generics, repository-pattern

I am currently fiddling with generic repositories. My test application is in C#. I have made a function that prints out all items in particular repository. A repository is an input parameter. The whole block is at the bottom of this post and currently the function itself looks like this:

```
static void PrintCollection<T, TKey>(IRepository<T, TKey> repo)
{
    // Error since compiler does not recognizes p.LastName
    //foreach (Person p in repo.GetItems().OrderBy(p => p.LastName)) Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
    foreach (T p in repo.GetItems())
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
}
```

It's working fine but it's missing things like ordering by particular property in a class, such as `LastName` in `Person` or `ProductName` in `Product`. I was wondering if it's possible to send an extra parameter to `PrintCollection<T, TKey>(...)` and test whether the particular field exists and then order by it. For instance:

```
static void PrintCollection<T, TKey, TOrder>(IRepository<T, TKey> repo, TOrder o = default(TOrder))
{
    if (o == default(TOrder))
        foreach (T p in repo.GetItems()) Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
    else
        // Order by o
}
```

At the moment, I don't know what I should use to test the fields and properties against their existance in a class. And then, how to use them in LINQ and Lambdsa Expression to e.g. order, sort, filter collections.

Thanks

---

Below is a snippet of my code. I cut out unimportant parts.

Main program

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PeopleRepository repPeople = new PeopleRepository();
        ProductsRepository repProduct = new ProductsRepository();

        PrintCollection(repPeople);
        PrintCollection(repProduct);
    }

    static void PrintCollection<T, TKey>(IRepository<T, TKey> repo)
    {
        // Error since compiler does not recognizes p.LastName
        //foreach (Person p in repo.GetItems().OrderBy(p => p.LastName)) Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
        foreach (T p in repo.GetItems()) Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
    }
}
```

Interface `IRepository`

```
interface IRepository<T, TKey>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetItems();
    T GetItem(TKey key);
    // ...
}
```

Repository for People

```
class PeopleRepository : IRepository<Person, string>
{
    private static List<Person> _proxy;

    public PeopleRepository(List<Person> people = null)
    {
        if(people == null) _proxy = Person.GetAllPeople();
        else _proxy = people;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetItems()
    {
        return _proxy;
    }

    public Person GetItem(string key)
    {
        return _proxy.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == key);
    }
}
```

Repository for Products

```
class ProductsRepository : IRepository<Product, int>
{
    private static List<Product> _proxy;

    public ProductsRepository(List<Product> products = null)
    {
        if (products == null) _proxy = Product.GetAllProducts();
        else _proxy = products;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetItems()
    {
        return _proxy;
    }

    public Product GetItem(int key)
    {
        return _proxy.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, using delegate for selecting order by clause:

```
static void PrintCollection<T, TKey, TOrder>(IRepository<T, TKey> repo, 
       Func<T,TOrder> orderBy)
{
    var items = repo.GetItems();
    if (orderBy != null)
        items = items.OrderBy(orderBy);
    foreach (T p in items)
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
}
```

you can call it like:

```
PrintCollection(repo, x=>x.Name);
```

For `Where` you need argument of type `Func<T,bool>` and the process is the same as above.

**Note:** If you use ORM like EF, the ORMs need entire expression tree in order to build the SQL statement for the query. As we pass a delegate, so the ordering or filtering does not translate to SQL. The ORM loads the data then applies ordering or filtering on it.

If you want to make sure they translate to SQL, the return type must be of type that implements `IQueryable` and the parameters for the function should change to `Expression<Func<T,TOrder>>` for `orderBy` and `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` for `while`.

**Suggestion**

Define this method as extension for `IEnumerable` :

```
public static class IEnumerableExtenstions
{
    static void PrintCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        foreach (T p in collection)
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
    }
}
```

and then you can call it like:

```
repo.GetItems().Where(x=>x.Age>15).OrderBy(x=>x.Name).PrintCollection();
```

which is more flexible and natural than defining parameters for each functionality in the function.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to work with EF and ORM. Thanks for the edit. As to `Func<>` I completely forgot I could use this delegate. Shame :p

Comment: Would it be difficult to change this function in such way that it would either sort, or filter, or order depending on my choice? It could be topic to another question though.

Comment: Not so difficult, you can add whatever parameter you want and then decide based on them, but I think the suggestion I added to my answer is a better choice.

Comment: Duplication of repo.GetItems(). You meant to use items the second time.